# Dockerfile - apt-get only?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, linuxbrew

I'm wondering what the different options there are with dockerfiles in terms of what I can use in the dockerfile definition (command-line) to install things.

I wanted to know if people are using Linuxbrew at all when they are using docker or if basically everyone is only just using apt-get in the case of Ubuntu which is the OS I'm going with.

Does it make sense to even use Linuxbrew (homebrew) if I'm doing everything via a dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

We've found great success with just executing the apt-get commands using RUN:

```
RUN apt-get update
```

RUN apt-get -y install build-essential ca-certificates libhiredis-dev \
   make gcc g++ libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libevent-dev python2.7-dev libbz2-dev

We build all of our docker images on a standard Linux machine, but if that wasn't the case I think we'd probably still do the same since it's all just docker.